# How to ignore the element below the clicked element - NonFactors MVC Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, nonfactors-mvc-grid

I am using [NonFactor MVC grid](http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/) to create a grid with clickable rows:

```
$('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid({
    reloadEnded: function () { $('.lds-facebook').hide(); },
    rowClicked: function (row, data, e) { window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Details","CRMTItems")/' + data.Id }
});
```

Where the html generated for a row looks like this

```
<tr class="Opportunity crmtRow">
        <td class="hidden">9</td>
        <td>Project Name</td>
        <td>Client Name</td>
        <td>Project Owner</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-default btn-sm rowWorkspaceLink pull-right" 
               href="http://google.com" 
               target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></a></td>
</tr>
```

[image]

So when I click on a row, it takes me to the view of that item, and if I click on the `glyphicon-globe`, it takes me to `http://google.com`

**The problem I'm seeing is that if I click on the globe, it does pop out a new tab with google, but then in the original tab it also navigates to the item page. When hovering over the globe, I can see that `hover` is also being applied the row element**

How can I get a click on the glyph icon to ignore the element below? I.e. if I click the globe icon, the page should not redirect, but a new tab should open and navigate to google

[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxkdL2zt/) illustrates my problem

Comment: try this fidle https://jsfiddle.net/hxkdL2zt/2/

Comment: I have added `return false`  and no need to add `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @user1608841 That works too, but it then prevents the navigation which I've already set up in my grid template. seems that in order to achieve what I want I have to give up on either the grid column template for the globe, **or** the `rockClicked` option in the grid initialisation

Comment: You can use event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

> `event.preventDefault();` If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be
>   triggered.
>
> `event.stopPropagation();`Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
//Add a click event listener for elements with class .glyphicon-globe
$('.rowWorkspaceLink .glyphicon-globe').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();   //Add this so that page will not open when click on .glyphicon
  event.stopPropagation();  //Add this so the the even of the parent will not be executed

  //Add the events for glyphicon
});
```

Doc: [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eddie, but that doesn't seem to have worked. I'm getting the same results after adding that snippet, interestingly if I middle-click on the globe, it behaves as required

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? if you click on globe, does it still redirect? @Bassie

Comment: Yes, I am seeing the same result as before

Comment: Can you clear or cache or something. I tried it and works just fine.

Comment: Eddie, I updated your fiddle with an example that is more representative of my scenario. Notice that if you click on the globe link now, it will fire both events https://jsfiddle.net/mck0dLof/2/

Comment: @Bassie Well if this is the case, you also need `event.stopPropagation();` Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mck0dLof/3/

Comment: I can see that working in the fiddle, but for some reason when I use it in my actual code it has no effect. I can't even get an `alert` to display in the click method.. how frustrating

Comment: Better to use `console.log()` for debugging. Did you add these HTML elements dynamically? I mean via js?

Comment: They are being created by the nonfactor grid library, so they are being added by some ajax somewhere. even calling `console.log` in the click event is doing nothing.. I dont get it

Comment: Ohh if that is the case we have to use `on` on adding event listeners. You cant use `click()` on dynamically added elements. Please try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mck0dLof/4/ @Bassie

Comment: Its the same again... The fiddle works great, but my code just doesn't behave. its weird, because when I click the globe, then the row click activates (page navigates to the item), but I'm not seeing the alert for the row click

Comment: Did you put the code inside `$(document).ready` ? and clear you cache

Comment: Ye, but I still get navigated to the row link.. maybe its just not worth it this is way too much work for such a simple feature

Comment: I added my own answer eddie

Answer (score 2):

This must be some quirk of the `Nonfactors Mvc-Grid library`, because when I do this it works fine

**Removed rowClicked option from grid init**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid({
        reloadEnded: function () { $('.lds-facebook').hide(); }
    });
```

**Added the following code as per Eddie's suggestion**

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on('click', '.rowWorkspaceLink .glyphicon-globe', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); //Add this so the the even of the parent will not be executed
    });


    $("body").on('click', '.crmtRow', function (event, data) {
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Details", "CRMTItems")/" + id;
    });
});
```

And now it seems to work. I say this must be caused by the `rowClicked` option somewhere in the NonFactors library, because this is not an issue in jsfiddle, and it now works fine after manually setting the row clicked event.